# Where should I install my app on Linux?

Tags: linux, centos

We have some data import tools we've written in-house and I need to set them up on a new Linux box.

These are written in both Java and .NET (running on Mono) and they comprise binaries, config files, resources/assets like images and templates. They also write logs and look to some special folders for the data to import.

I'm new to Linux. At the moment, they're in a folder like `/data/importer.java/` and `/data/importManager.net/` with these folders containing everything they need to run.

But I see `/data/` is a non-standard folder. So I wanted to know if there's a proper place to set them up, however it seems the on Linux, there's many, many folders each for a specific purpose and for read-only/read-write data.

Its almost as if I need to split my apps over a bunch of folders to do it properly, and some folder names, like `bin` sound right but then what do I with non-binary/compiled files?

Aside from the binaries, the config and everything else is often modified by humans.

Something like (just focusing on the Java part for now):

- `/opt/importer.java/` for the binaries, config and resources
- `/var/importer.java/data-in/` for dropping in data to import
- `/var/importer.java/logs` for the logs written

Or maybe I should use the `/srv/` folder? Or perhaps `/usr/bin/`. Maybe logs should be written to the `/home/` folder of the running user?

It's all so complicated. Whenever I read any Linux documentation I regret it. Should I just copy it all over from the other machine as-is and forget I ever tried?

Thanks

Luke

Comment: What you're doing there looks pretty fine to me. Choice between putting the data into `/var` is especially good as that just makes sense in my humble opinion. Having the application specific folders, be that under `/opt` or `/var` is a good option as well. I'd put binaries into `/opt/<myapp>/bin` and then let users place that in their `$PATH` or create symlinks to `/usr/local/bin` or whatever they wish.

Comment: Review the FHS, it is the closest we have to a standard.  http://www.pathname.com/fhs/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a question with no right answer and an intriguing bit of [Unix history.](http://www.osnews.com/story/25556/Understanding_the_bin_sbin_usr_bin_usr_sbin_Split/)

The rule we followed at my prior employer was that non-out-of-the-box software was installed in `/opt/PackageName-VersionNumber` and there was a symbolic link from `/opt/PackageName-VersionNumber` to `/opt/PackageName`.

Configs go in `/opt/PackageName/etc`
Logs go in `/opt/PackageName/logs`
Binaries go in `/opt/PackageName/bin`
Data goes in `/opt/PackageName/data`

For apps that were to be distributed outside of our shop we wrote them to be relocatable by the package manager. This was a rare occurrence, and not "fun".

Comment: That'll do for me. I have seen other talk of using /opt/company-name/app-name

Comment: Is it ok with folder /var . I see usual etc/local/ ... I i wanna use already shared location? I mean node.js app and similar... Is it /var safe place for server code?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware native linux applications are written to have their binaries in `[/usr]/bin`, logs in `/var`, config in `/etc`, and so on. Non native applications or combinations of packages (such as lampp/xampp for example) that are meant to be used systemwide, on the other hand are by default installed in `/opt`, with the configuration usually also residing in that folder. If the software is meant to run per user a folder inside their home directory is customary.